# Sharing heap memory with fork()

Tags: c++, c, fork, heap-memory, shared-memory

I am working on implementing a database server in C that will handle requests from multiple clients. I am using `fork()` to handle connections for individual clients.

The server stores data in the heap, which consists of a root pointer to hash tables of dynamically allocated records. The records are structs that have pointers to various data-types. I would like for the processes to be able to share this data so that, when a client makes a change to the heap, the changes will be visible for the other clients.

I have learned that `fork()` uses [COW (Copy On Write)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), and my understanding is that it copies the heap (and stack) memory of the parent process when the child tries to modify the data in memory.

I have found out that I can use the shm library to share memory.

Would the code below be a valid way to share heap memory (in shared_string)? If a child were to use similar code (i.e. starting from //start), would other children be able to read/write to it while the child is running and after it's dead?

```
key_t key;
int shmid;

key = ftok("/tmp",'R');
shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);

//start
char * string;
string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

strcpy(string, "a string");

char * shared_string;

shared_string = shmat(shmid, string, 0);

strcpy(shared_string, string);
```

Here are some of my thoughts/concerns regarding this:

- I'm thinking about sharing the root pointer of the database. I'm not sure if that would work or if I have to mark all allocated memory as shared.
- I'm not sure if the parent / other children are able to access memory allocated by a child.
- I'm not sure if a child's allocated memory stays on the heap after it is killed, or if that memory is released.

Comment: It's more common to use *threads* if you want to share memory between sections of the same program. But you have to be very careful about how you synchronize access to the shared data structures with locks, etc.

Comment: Well, you need to use shared memory for all stuff you want to share.

Comment: Only shm can be shared, if you allocate new memory, it has to be on shm too, no short-cut.

Comment: If you must use `fork()`, you will need to use shared memory (in some shape or form) for the common data, and ensure you control access to that data very carefully.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the copy-on-write semantics.  It occurs for *both* processes, and reproduces the original UNIX semantics of making a complete duplicate image of the parent process for the child.  No "logical" sharing of storage occurs, even though physically some (read-only) storage is shared.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `fork` is completely inappropriate for what you're trying to achieve. Even if you can make it work, it's a horrible hack. In general, `fork` only works for very simplistic programs anyway, and I would go so far as to say that `fork` should never be used except followed quickly by `exec`, but that's aside from the point here. You really should be using threads.

With that said, the only way to have memory that's shared between the parent and child after `fork`, and where the same pointers are valid in both, is to `mmap` (or `shmat`, but that's a lot fuglier) a file or anonymous map with `MAP_SHARED` prior to the `fork`. You cannot create new shared memory like this after `fork` because there's no guarantee that it will get mapped at the same address range in both.

Just don't use `fork`. It's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Agreed. Fork() creates a separate, mostly identical instance. Threading is what is needed. Or asio, which can be complicated, but Boost does a pretty decent job at providing it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are basically looking to do what is done by Redis (and probably others).
They describe it in http://redis.io/topics/persistence (search for "copy-on-write").

- threads defeat the purpose
- classic shared memory (shm, mapped memory) also defeats the purpose

The primary benefit to using this method is avoidance of locking, which can be a pain to get right.

As far as I understand it the idea of using COW is to:

- fork when you want to write, not in advance
- the child (re)writes the data to disk, then immediately exits
- the parent keeps on doing its work, and detects (SIGCHLD) when the child exited.
  If while doing its work the parent ends up making changes to the hash, the kernel
  will execute a copy for the affected blocks (right terminology?).
  A "dirty flag" is used to track if a new fork is needed to execute a new write.

Things to watch out for:

- Make sure only one outstanding child
- Transactional safety: write to a temp file first, then move it over so that you always have a complete copy, maybe keeping the previous around if the move is not atomic.
- test if you will have issues with other resources that get duplicated (file descriptors, global destructors in c++)

You may want to take  gander at the [redis code](https://github.com/antirez/redis) as well

Comment: A temporary file is not strictly necessary: you can use a pipe to communicate the changes initiated by the child back to the parent. With that approach, each child would have a consistent, atomical view of the entire data while the master does not need any locking to ensure consistency. That way, you can even have multiple childs at once, each with its own unchanging, consistent view of the data, and one master that updates the data as instructed by the childs between forking new childs.

Comment: @cmaster the temp file is NOT intended as a lock, synch between threads or anything like that.  If for atomicity in the filesystem.  You can crash mid-write and have a bad file.  if you complete your write you then rename (atomic).

Comment: I never thought so. What I tried to point out is, that forking can be seen as a cheap checkpoint of all the data in memory. One process may freely analyse the data, while the master is already busy applying the changes communicated back from another child. In such a setup, you don't need to write any data to disk to communicate. And the point of such a setup would not be to persist data, but to ensure bulletproof, concurrent access to an in-memory database.

Comment: Ok, I guess I answered how I used COW. Where my end goal was persistence.  In the case you describe I think generally makes sense as long as one side (child?) treats the memory as read only.  Primary point in my answer was that if you decide to use COW it doesn't make sense to use classic shared memory

Answer (score 1):

> I'm thinking about sharing the root pointer of the database. I'm not sure if that would work or if I have to mark all allocated memory as shared.

Each process will have its own private memory range. Copy-on-write is a kernel-space optimization that is transparent to user space.

As others have said, SHM or mmap'd files are the only way to share memory between separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you must you `fork`, the shared memory seems to be the 'only' choice.

Actually, I think in your scene, the thread is more suitable.

If you don't want to be multi-threaded. Here is another choice,you can only use one-process & one-thread mode, like [redis](http://redis.io)

With this mode,you don't need worry about something like `lock` and if you want to scale, just design a route policy,as route with the hash value of the `key`

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, if you want to share memory between separate processes (from fork or otherwise), you need to use shared memory, either the SYSV shm library or mmap with MAP_SHARED.  Unfortunately, these are coarse-grained tools, suitable only for dealing with a small number of large blocks, and not suitable for fine-grained memory management as you would do with malloc/free.

In order to have *useful* shared memory between processes, you need to build a heap on top of shm or mmap.  You can do that with my small [shm_malloc library](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/shm_malloc), which allows you to use calls to `shm_malloc` and `shm_free` exactly as you would use malloc/free.